# installing a single rpm multiple times on one server

Tags: rpm

Hello and thanks ahead of time for any answers that anyone can provide for this question.

I have an RPM that is essentially a wrapper around an exploded WAR.  On my server I run

```
rpm -i myRPM.rpm
```

this works just fine and all is right with the world.  I then would like to run the rpm again with the --relocate trigger to create an identical install.  Ideally I would like to have it install the application with a new entry in the rpm data base with an incremented instance or something of that nature.

I can force the install to happen by running

```
rpm -i --force --relocate  OLDPATH=NEWPATH myRPM.rpm
```

The problem here however is that the old version is no longer managed by rpm.
Is there anything I can do to make this work the way I want?

Answer (score 3):

No. RPM maintains a database of files, installed RPMs etc. The way this DB is designed, a file (normally) can only belong to 1 RPM and this RPM will only have 1 copy of this file. I.e., it cannot track multiple copies of it at multiple locations (--relocate).

In general, relocating RPMs are a very bad idea - if you rely on this for your application I would seriously reconsider.

See this: https://rpm.org/user_doc/multiple_versions.html for some good ideas on how you can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer - but maybe it's not too late.

If you really need to install multiple versions of a unique software with rpm on the same machine you simply can use an alternative rpm database.

```
mkdir $HOME/rpm 
rpm --dbpath $HOME/rpm --initdb # older version need the initialization
rpm --dbpath $HOME/rpm -i --relocate OLDPATH=NEWPATH myRPM.rpm
```

This approach can be used to hot deploy or blue/green deploy daemons on one machine.